# Tamanho de um intervalo pré definido dentro de um vetor

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber como eu posso calcular a quantidade de elementos que tem em um intervalo pré definido, dentro de um vetor.

Por exemplo: Digamos que tenho um vetor de tamanho 10. Meu intuito por exemplo é querer saber quantos elementos tem entre o segundo elemento do meu vetor até o sexto elemento do meu vetor.

```
vetor=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Quero saber quantos numeros eu tenho entre o segundo elemento do meu vetor(`vetor[2]`) e o sexto elemento (`vetor[6]`). Que neste caso são 5 elementos.

OBS: Neste caso eu quero que o segundo e o sexto elemento façam parte da contagem.

Comment: Se eu entendi direito você quer apenas contar o número de elementos entre duas posições `n1` e `n2`. Nesse caso, é só uma questão matemática, independente de qualquer linguagem. Basta fazer a conta: `numero = n2 - n1 + 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, como o Luiz Vieira falou, neste caso você pode simplesmente calcular.

De qualquer forma, apenas para não deixar sem uma resposta, você pode fazer o subset do seu vetor primeiro `vetor[2:6]` e depois contar quantos elementos o subset do vetor tem utilizando `length`:

```
vetor=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
length(vetor[2:6])
[1] 5
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda!